# Como colocar textos em progress

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

Olá, eu tenho uma `progress`, porém eu gostaria de adicionar o valor da porcentagem no centro dela, com mais algumas informações.

```
        <progress name="progressbar" id="progressbar" class="progressbar" value="35" max="100"> 
        </progress>
```

Answer (score 2):

Com só com css/html não sei como seria, mas aqui está uma solução com javascript:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("progbar");   
var width = 1
var timer = setInterval(function() {
   if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(timer);
   } else {
      width++; 
      elem.innerHTML = width+ '%'
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
   }
}, 20);
```

```css
#progress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#progbar {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000:
  height: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  <div id="progbar">0%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso definindo a informação dentro do progress e exibindo com `css` utilizando pseudo elementos `after` e `before` do `css`. Esses elementos não existem dentro do `DOM`, só existem para adicionar informações referentes ao estilo da página.

Pode fazer dessa forma:

```css
progress::after {
 content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<progress name="progressbar" id="progressbar" class="progressbar" value="35" max="100" data-content="35% do progresso"></progress>
```